# Getting error when deploying on aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, deployment, staging

I'm deploying a rubyonrails project and getting following error when using '**cap staging deploy**':

```
Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/icare/git-ssh.sh" ; 
/usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads ssh://github.com/RaghavVishnoi/icare.git )

DEBUG [a492d051]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [a492d051]    
DEBUG [a492d051]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [a492d051]    
DEBUG [a492d051]    
DEBUG [a492d051]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [a492d051]    
DEBUG [a492d051]    and the repository exists.

DEBUG [a492d051]    
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)

cap aborted!

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as 

deploy@54.213.40.141: git exit status: 128

git stdout: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: did you update the ssh public key of your machine to the github where you have a access to that repo?

Comment: ssh -vT git@github.com did you try ?

Comment: yes i already did it and got

Comment: Transferred: sent 4080, received 2056 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7007.5, received 3531.2
debug1: Exit status 1

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: hmmm ssh-add -D   #remove existing identities then ssh-add try this

Comment: added identity as u said but still getting same error

Comment: run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and try deploying again

Comment: this problem has resolved when accessing repository using https..